# Spring Boot HashiCorp vault register on Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, consul, spring-cloud-netflix, hashicorp-vault

While information exists on the internet, in how you can enable discoveryClient to find the vault service within a spring boot application.

e.g. `spring.cloud.vault.discovery.enabled: true`

No information exists in how you actually can register HashiCorp Vault to Eureka.

How can I register the HashiCorp Vault to Eureka?

Comment: // , Not sure why this was downvoted, but I have my suspicions. Would you be willing to flesh out your example code a little more? Also, did you ever make any posts in the Vault forums? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help other people in the future.

I was hoping to find a good solution (aka HashiCorp Vault, supporting Eureka or in a general manner), but I don't think anything will happen anytime soon (see Consul).

The best other solution is making use of something what Netflix calls, a 'side car'.

This means, you will start a microservice that will register HashiCorp Vault in Eureka.

> spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar